# What is org.apache.commons.text.diff used for?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I read the documentation of `org.apache.commons.text.diff`. But I still couldn't understand what the classes `InsertCommand`, `EditCommand`, `KeepCommand` and `DeleteCommand` can be used for. Does anybody know what they're all about and how they can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare two strings:

`A B C   E F  H` *(old)*
`A   C D E  G H` *(new)*

Then your "script" is:

```
Keep   'A'
Delete 'B'
Keep   'C'
Insert 'D'
Keep   'E'
Delete 'F'
Insert 'G'
Keep   'H'
```

As described in the javadoc of [`EditCommand`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/diff/EditCommand.html):

> When two objects sequences are compared through the `StringsComparator.getScript` method, the result is provided has a `script` containing the commands that progressively transform the first sequence into the second one.